# jquery hyperlink with image

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which when I hover over a hyperlink, I like to show the image of it.
The problem is that no image comes up.

Here is what it looks like

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a').hover(function (e) {

          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          alert(href); // shows c:/images/jj.gif for that particular record as I have the hyperlinks for a given column within a grid

          $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + this.href + "' alt='Image preview' /></p>");


      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5jLd/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function(e) {

        var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
        $(e.target).next('div').append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + href + "' alt='Image preview' /></p>");

    },function(){   // i have added this when mouse out of the link 
                    // preview will be destroyed.

        $('#preview').remove();

    });
});
```

You were hovering a link but not capturing the target itself. so `e.target` selects the hovering  item.

Comment: Thanks. As I have a grid, this image shows way at the bottom of the grid. How do I get it show next to each hyperlink for each row?

Comment: @WebDev you mean (grid) some div or td. Need some more suggestions. If this is the case that you have a div next to the link then you have to append to that div with .next(), i am updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('a').hover(function (e) {

          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          alert(href); // shows c:/images/jj.gif for that particular record as I have the hyperlinks for a given column within a grid

          $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + href + "' alt='Image preview' /></p>");


      });
  });
```

if you've already assigned href to a variable you don't need to reference it as this.href